# How to copy the packages from CentOS iso image?

Tags: linux, centos, iso-image, cp

#### Objective:

To copy packages to hard disk from CentOS iso image on CentOS 7

#### Procedure Followed:

1. `mkdir /home/ava/linux`
2. `mount -o loop -t iso9660 /media/sdb1/CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1708.iso /home/ava/linux/`
3. `mkdir /home/ava/packages`
4. `cp -a /home/ava/linux/Packages/ /home/ava/packages/`

#### Problem Encountered:

OS crashes abruptly

Please advise how to copy the packages to hard disk properly.

Comment: "OS crashes abruptly" What?

Comment: Exactly - at what stage does the OS crash, how does it crash?  There is no reason any of the above commands should be able to cause the OS to crash, so unless its faulty hardware (or conceivably a faulty ISO), this is coincidental.